убрать все символы по списку из конца строки
В конце строки может быть любой из символов " - / или пробел
если задать выражение в preg_replace('!["\s-/]$!m','',$text) , то убирается только один из списка символов, если там несколько.
Например Hello word- " -  уберется только последний минус, а нужно убрать все имеющиеся.

rtrim как и модификатор + уже изобретены.

Да, спасибо! Уже после написания вопроса - нашел описание rtrim(), он решает проблему.
$hello  = "Hello World";
$trimmed = rtrim($hello, "Hdle");
var_dump($trimmed);

string(9) "Hello Wor"

